# Grafana query to generate a cumulative sum from the same time every day

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux-influxdb

I need to present a Grafana time series graph starting at 05:00 every day. The time series graph needs to show a cumulative sum of 2 mass flow meters until 05:00 the next day, at which time it resets to zero, and then starts summing again.

What I have so far is the cumulative sum figured out, but have manually set the range to 05:00.

```
  from(bucket: "ShortTerm")
  |> range(start: 2021-09-17T05:05:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "pulp_mflow1" or r["_measurement"] == 
    "pulp_mflow2")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> cumulativeSum()
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

At first `hourSelection` came to mind, but it does not seem to handle midnight rollover. So for lack of better way, this may work:

```js
import "date"
import "experimental"

hour = date.hour(t: now())
d0 = date.truncate(t: now(), unit: 1d)
t0 = if hour >= 5 then experimental.addDuration(d: 5h, to: d0) else experimental.subDuration(d: 19h, from: d0)

from(bucket: "ShortTerm")
  |> range(start: t0)
```